# Prove or disprove the following statements

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $B=\{5,6,7,8\}$ and $f,g,h$ be functions from $B$ to $B$.

1) For all $f,g,h$, if $f\circ g = f\circ h$ and $f$ is one to one then $g=h$.

I think this one is true but I'm not quite sure how to write the proof. Do I assume for example $a,b$ are integers and then $f(g(a)) = f(h(b))$. Then how can I say that $g(a) = h(b)$ and that $g=h$?

2) For all $f,g,h$, if $g \circ f = h \circ f$ and $f$ is onto then $g = h$.

I think this one is also true but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

Let $x \in B$,

$$(f \circ g)(x) = (f \circ h)(x)$$

That is $f(g(x))=f(h(x))$, since $f$ is injective, we have $g(x)=h(x)$.

2) Let $y \in B$, since $f$ is onto, $\exists x \in B$ such that $f(x)=y$.

$g(f(x))=h(f(x))$, hence $g(y)=h(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

For your first statement, you need to start evaluating the composite functions in the same integer, otherwise you cannot prove that they are equal! So, take any $x\in B$.

What do we know? We know that, for all $x\in B$, $(f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ h)(x)$, and that, for all $y,z\in B$, $f(y)=f(z)$ only if $y=z$ (this is the definition of one-to-one function).

What do we want? We want to see that $g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in B$.

We start with any $x\in B$. We assume that $(f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ h)(x)$, which means that $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(h(x)\bigr)$. Now we call $g(x)=y$ and $h(x)=z$, so $f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(h(x)\bigr)$ can be rewritten as $f\bigl(y\bigr)=f\bigl(z\bigr)$. But $f$ is one-to-one so, necessarily, $y=z$, i.e., $g(x)=h(x)$. This is for any $x\in B$, so $g(x)=h(x)$ always, therefore $g=h$.